# argument of @sect has an extra run away argument

Tags: errors, amsmath, sections-paragraphs

I am new to latex, so excuse me.

I keep getting "argument of @sect has an extra run away  argument" and I don't know how to fix it. Thanks

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newenvironment{psmallmatrix}
  {\left(\begin{smallmatrix}}
  {\end{smallmatrix}\right)}


\begin{document}

\section{\small  $A= \begin{psmallmatrix}1 & 2\\-1 & 1\end{psmallmatrix}$ }

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Don't worry and there's nothing for you to apologize for. We're all here to help each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fragile commands should be protected. Here `\small`, `\begin` and `\end`. I'd avoid `\small`, though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newenvironment{psmallmatrix}
  {\left(\begin{smallmatrix}}
  {\end{smallmatrix}\right)}

\begin{document}

\section{\protect\small
  $A=\protect\begin{psmallmatrix}1 & 2\\-1 & 1\protect\end{psmallmatrix}$}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Math constructs in `\section` etc. titles are highly fragile and shouldn't be written, in my point of view.

However, if really needed, wrap the matrix etc. in a robust command that can't be broken during the writing process to the `.aux` and `.toc` files.

The `mathtools` package provides a `psmallmatrix` environment already, so no need to define it on your own.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{enumitem}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\mymatrix}[2]{%
  #1= \begin{psmallmatrix}#2
  \end{psmallmatrix}}%

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{\texorpdfstring{\small $\mymatrix{A}{1 & 2 \\    -1 & 1}$}{The matrix $A$}}


\end{document}
```